# How to show contours on face using google ml kit in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-mlkit

I want to detect face and show contours.I have detected the face but how to show contours.Any suggestions is accepted.I have searched on google but I did't find find solution;

```
class FacePainter extends CustomPainter {
  ui.Image image;
  List<Face> faces;
  List<Rect> rects = [];

  FacePainter(this.image, this.faces) {
    for (var i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
      rects.add(faces[i].boundingBox);
    }
    print("object");
  }
  @override
  void paint(ui.Canvas canvas, ui.Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0
      ..color = Colors.blue;
    canvas.drawImage(image, Offset.zero, paint);
    for (var i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
      canvas.drawRect(rects[i], paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FacePainter oldDelegate) {
    return image != oldDelegate.image || image != oldDelegate.faces;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I  got the solution:

```
class FacePainter extends CustomPainter {
  ui.Image image;
  List<Face> faces;
  List<Rect> boundingBoxes = [];
  List<Map<FaceContourType, FaceContour?>> contours = [];

  FacePainter(this.image, this.faces) {
    for (var face in faces) {
      boundingBoxes.add(face.boundingBox);
      contours.add(face.contours);
    }
  }

  @override
  void paint(ui.Canvas canvas, ui.Size size) {
    final Paint boundingBoxPaint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0
      ..color = Colors.blue;

    final Paint contourPaint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0
      ..color = Colors.blue;

    canvas.drawImage(image, Offset.zero, Paint());

    for (var i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
      canvas.drawRect(boundingBoxes[i], boundingBoxPaint);
      final faceContour = contours[i];
      for (var faceContourType in faceContour.keys) {
        final contour = faceContour[faceContourType];
        final points = contour!.points;
        if (points.isNotEmpty) {
          canvas.drawPoints(
              ui.PointMode.points,
              points
                  .map((e) => Offset(e.x.toDouble(), e.y.toDouble()))
                  .toList(),
              contourPaint);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FacePainter oldDelegate) {
    return image != oldDelegate.image || faces != oldDelegate.faces;
  }
}
```